# Accessing image link in JS slideshow

Tags: javascript, image, href

Beginner learning Javascript so please be patient. Javascript only. No JQuery.

I have created a Javascript slideshow of images which fades in and out by changing the class (opacity values) of the img tags (which are added individually via a for loop in the JS script-not the html).

I seem to be unable to get the link for the current image to open a new page with only that image. I have tried adding  tags around each image with href links. This looks fine in the debugger --> elements, but when I hover on the image, the slideshow stops (as requested) but it always links through to the last images link as opposed to the current.

I first tried using getAttribute ("href") and then the img tag's parentNode attribute. Neither worked (only returned the href of the last image??!!). I'm wondering how I access this and ensure all  tags except the ones around the current image are hidden or not active? Another option I have tried is creating new Div elements for the image (and  elements) but this did not work either.

`JS Fiddle`  https://jsfiddle.net/f5yt7rna/

Comment: please add the code to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Now make to make current element on top of stack. Use script below

```
#container img.show, a.show {
opacity:1;
z-index:1000
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed the obvious. The link was there but below the last link in the stack. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index:100` to the `#container img.show, a.show` rule so that the visible item is on-top of the other and its link is the one that will get the click.